# 'And' operator in Linq

Tags: linq

I have a query that prints userid in label1 when username is entered.Works fine; but i want to write query for username and password that prints userid. so how can i write it? i tried writing using 'and' operator but dont seems to work.

```
int id = (from auser in lq.logins
          where auser.username == userNameString //&& auser.Password =pwdString
          select auser.userid).SingleOrDefault();

label1.Text = id.ToString();
```

Thanks
Ani

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It probably doesn't work becase you used `=` instead of `==`.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you used the assignment operator `=` instead of the comparison operator `==`. The query should be:

```
int id = (from auser in lq.logins
          where auser.username == userNameString && auser.Password == pwdString
          select auser.userid).SingleOrDefault();

label1.Text = id.ToString();
```

Comment: can u also tell me how to write inset quer in Linq.

Comment: @Ani: you definitely have to read this: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx